# Can I use http for Google Place api for ios?

Tags: ios, google-maps, http, google-places-api

I am making an app that uses Google's Place Api. On Google's developer website there are four options for the place api: Andriod, iOS, JS, and http. Because I am using the api in an ios app I thought to use the ios option. However in the sample code they provided seems a little odd in that they don't use an url to make a http request. So then I went on http and I was familiar with the approach. You make an url and add all the necessary parameters. So can I use the http approach for google place api inmy ios app?

Comment: Certainly you can. But iOS API wrapped network call, error handling, etc. for you and give you the result via delegate methods, which is much easier for you to use.

Comment: I actually already created the app with yahoo api. But since yahoo api got discontinued I want to use google place api now. So all I need to do is replace the url, api key, and neccesary parameters? Or will there be alot more work.

Comment: Theoretically yes. you might however meet other issues like error response difference, etc.

Comment: Ok thank you for help